# Запуск BroadcastReceiver при загрузке

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Можно ли как то запустить активность, которая запускается с помощью BroadcastReceiver при загрузке до появления рабочего стола? В данный момент активность стартует когда загрузился рабочий стол.
Делаю так:
AndroiManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver
       android:name=".Reciver" 
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="true" >
              <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
                </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent intent12 = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
            intent12.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent12);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Поясните зачем вам это и, возможно, получится предложить иной подход к решению задачи.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пишу экран блокировки

Comment: Т.к. многие никогда не вникали в эту тему, то может быть непонятно как связать написание экрана блокировки с нуждой исполнения к-л кода до полной загрузки девайса

Comment: @ЮрийСПб без этого весь смысл экрана блокировки теряется, я пишу приложение, которое дает доступ к телефону только по идентификации лица, и всё уже готово, кроме этого, а без этого весь смысл данного приложения теряется, только, если использовать данное приложение поверх стандартного локскрина, но тогда тоже сомнительная польза от приложения

Comment: К сожалению в теме совершенно не разбираюсь и ничего посоветовать не могу. Неужели нема API для подмены лок скрина?.. И типа аналогов вашей задумки нема нигде?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб К сожалению сколько не искал найти не смог, есть вариант использовать активити, как кастомный локскрин, но тогда, по какой то причине пропадает кастомный лаунчер, т.е. локскрин становится и локскрином и экраном блокировки, и при разблокировке он отправляет сам на себя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28781050/3212712), это невозможно, т.к. нет соответствующего интента. По ссылке также упоминается особый интент, коий рассылается раньше `BOOT_COMPLETED`, но только на `HTC` девайсах, так что в качестве общего решения не подойдёт.

Comment: жаль, но впрочем я так и думал, т.к. в принципе я бы смог написать подобие вируса, которое полностью блокирует экран)